Only one irreducible component through point when it's a cusp of curve
I'm studying the basics of plane algebraic curves through Gathmann's class notes.
Here's one of the exercises:
If $F$ has a cusp at $P$, prove that $F$ has only one irreducible component passing through $P$.
Because we can change variables we can assume that $P$ is the origin, without loss of generality. From the definition of a cusp, we have that

The multiplicity of $F$ at the origin is $m_0(F)=2$.

There is exactly one tangent $L$ to $F$ at the origin.

The intersection multiplicity of $F$ and $L$ is $\mu_0(F,L)=3$.


So the smallest non-zero homogeneous part of $F$ has degree $2$ and it has only one linear factor.
I'm assuming that $F_2$ will look something like $F_2=(x+c)G$.
I'm struggling on how to proceed. Is there any key idea I'm missing?

Suppose $F$ has two distinct irreducible components, $G$ and $H$, through the cusp point $p$. Then $I(C,F;p)$, the intersection multiplicity of $F$ with a curve $C$ at the point $p$, satisfies $I(C,F;p)=I(C,G;p)+I(C,H;p)$. Taking $C$ to be an arbitrary line $L$ through $P$, we know that $I(L,G;p)$ and $I(L,H;p)$ are both at least one, and greater than one iff $L$ is a tangent direction to $G$ or $H$ at $p$.
When $L$ is a tangent direction to $G$ or $H$, we have $I(L,F;p)=I(L,G;p)+I(L,H;p)\geq 3$. On the other hand, there is a unique line through $p$ such that $I(L,F;p)=3$, so it must be the case that $G$ and $H$ have exactly one tangent direction each, and it must be the same. But then taking $L$ to be that tangent direction, we see $I(L,F;p)\geq 4$, contradicting the definition of a cusp.
(You can translate this back to be a more algebraic condition if you'd like - the basic gist of it is that if you want to factor $y^2+p(x,y)y+cx^3+\cdots$ for $p(x,y)$ homogeneous of degree two and $c$ a nonzero constant, your factors must be of the shape $y+\cdots$ and $y+\cdots$, and there's no way to get $cx^3$ from that.)
